# Adobe Animate project works fine inside the project but goes in loop when published

Tags: flash, animation, adobe

Is there any solution except redoing all the work?
this is my project working just fine inside Adobe Animate (ctrl+enter)
[working fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JF6QT.png)

and here when published(.swf), it goes into a loop
[not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsA1d.png)

Now i came to know that i should have done it on multiple layers, but it works fine inside Adobe so why wouldn't it work outside? is there any solution besides redoing the work? Thanks.

Comment: Though looking at your screenshot I see flash player 8,  which is ancient and likely your issue as I doubt AnimateCC even supports anything less than 11 (unconfirmed).  Check your publishing settings to see what version of flash you're outputting (target).

Comment: Thank you guys! the problem came to to be that Adobe Animate CC was exporting to flash player version 26 so i had to update my flash player, thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your screenshot,  I see you using FlashPlayer 8 to run your published SWF.     Adobe Animate by default will output to the latest version of flash (currently 26+) which will include things that will not work on the very old Flash Player 8.

Try updating your stand-alone flash player (or browser plugins) to the latest version (or at least a version that matches your output in Animate).

To change the targeted flash version of your program,  go to the publish settings (*Ctrl+Shift+F12*  or   *File -> Publish Settings*) and change the **target** to a version that matches or is less than your version of the stand-alone flash player being used.

Comment: Thank you, this really is the problem, and i solved it, thank you!